Import *.mcap file into foxglove and get error: invalid wire type 4 at offset 21
I'm trying to generate a *.mcap file based on my own protobuf defination based on the example. (https://github.com/foxglove/mcap/tree/main/cpp)
But it seems the generated mcap file couldn't decoded by foxglove.
Foxglove software gave me the error: invalid wire type 4 at offset 21.
Please help to see what's the problem’
here is my main cpp function.
#include
#include
#include "mcap/writer.hpp"
#include
#include "serialize_mv_planning_output_info.h"
#define MCAP_IMPLEMENTATION
// #include <mcap/writer.hpp>

#include
#include
#include
#include
#include

//
mcap::Timestamp now() {
return mcap::Timestamp(std::chrono::duration_caststd::chrono::nanoseconds(
std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch())
.count());
}

int main() {
//
mcap::McapWriter writer;
auto status = writer.open("output.mcap", mcap::McapWriterOptions("protobuf"));

if (!status.ok()) {
std::cerr << "Failed to open MCAP file for writing: " << status.message << "\n";
return 1;
}

//
mcap::Schema mvPlanningOutputInfoSchema(
"MvPlanningOutputInfoTest",
"protobuf",
R"proto(
message MvPlanningOutputInfo {
int32 id = 1;
float x = 2;
float y = 3;
string name = 4;
}
)proto"
);
writer.addSchema(mvPlanningOutputInfoSchema);

//
mcap::Channel planningOutputChannel(
"/planning_output",
"protobuf",
mvPlanningOutputInfoSchema.id
);
writer.addChannel(planningOutputChannel);

//
MvPlanningOutputInfo info;
info.id = 123;
info.x = 10.5;
info.y = 20.5;
info.name = "SampleName";

//
std::vectorstd::byte serializedData = serializeMvPlanningOutputInfo(info);

//
mcap::Status TransferState;
mcap::Message msg;
msg.channelId = planningOutputChannel.id;
msg.sequence = 1; //
msg.logTime = now(); //
msg.publishTime = msg.logTime; //
msg.dataSize = serializedData.size();
msg.data = serializedData.data();

TransferState = writer.write(msg);
if (!TransferState.ok()) {
std::cerr << "Failed to write message to MCAP file: " << TransferState.message << "\n";
return 1;
}

//
writer.close();

return 0;
}

And there is my subfunction named serializeMvPlanningOutputInfo
// serialize_mv_planning_output_info.cpp

#include "serialize_mv_planning_output_info.h"
#include "writer.inl"
#include "types.inl"
#include
#include

std::vectorstd::byte serializeMvPlanningOutputInfo(const MvPlanningOutputInfo& info) {
//
MvPlanningOutputInfoProto protoMsg;

// 
protoMsg.set_id(info.id);
protoMsg.set_x(info.x);
protoMsg.set_y(info.y);
protoMsg.set_name(info.name);

// 
std::string binaryData;
bool successState = protoMsg.SerializeToString(&binaryData);
if (!successState) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to serialize MvPlanningOutputInfo\n";
    return {};
}
const uint32_t length = binaryData.size();
//
std::vectorstd::byte serializedData(binaryData.size()+4);
std::memcpy(serializedData.data(), &length, 4);
std::memcpy(serializedData.data() + 4, binaryData.data(), binaryData.size()+4);
return serializedData;
}

I tried to simplify the proto defination (e.g. only one member variable in a struct). but got the same error.`
